# How can I take select rows in matrix from vector in R

Tags: r, select, vector, matrix

I have the matrix y with variable x:

```
         x
 [1,]    0
 [2,]    1
 [3,]    0
 [4,]    0
 [5,]    1
 [6,]    1
```

I selected just values with 1. Now I have a vector z:

```
 2 5 6
```

I need match this vector with lines selected with my matrix y. This a example, I have a big data. I tried y[z], but this don't show the rows. Thanks

Comment: you're missing a comma: `y[z,]`

Comment: Don't work,because I need a new matrix: [2,] 1 [4,] 1 [6,] 1. Do you  understand?

Comment: I don't quite understand, but if you want to convert a vector into a matrix, you can call `as.matrix(your_vector)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`y[z,]` returns matrix `y` with rows `z`.

`y[z]` returns elements `z` of matrix `y`

```
> y <- matrix(1:12, ncol=3)
> y
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    7   11
[4,]    4    8   12
> y[c(2,3),]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    6   10
[2,]    3    7   11
> y[c(2,3)]
[1] 2 3
```

As Joran points out, if you are working with a single column matrix, include `,drop=FALSE` to make sure your output is a matrix.

Comment: I think this needs an explanation of what `y[c(5,6)]` does; also choosing a different matrix may be a bit less confusing, smth as simple as using `matrix(12:1, ncol = 3)` instead

Comment: The OP's example, being a single column, combined with their comment that they need the output to be a _matrix_ would perhaps suggest that it would be worthwhile mentioning the famous `drop = FALSE` feature.

Comment: @eddi You're doing it wrong. You're missing a comma. Check `?Extract`.

Comment: ahhh, great, thanks! :) so for the record `m[1:3,,drop=FALSE]`

Comment: for the record, what I was doing wrong was `m[1:3,drop=FALSE]`